# How to test EIP-2981 implementation with hardhat/ethers

Tags: erc-721, ethers.js, hardhat, opensea, royalties

My goal is to mint an NFT collection and then import it onto OpenSea. I know you can [import an existing](https://opensea.io/get-listed/step-two) ERC-721 contract onto OpenSea, but I'm trying to figure out how secondary sales work and if they're compatible with the [EIP-2981](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981) royalties standard. I'm guessing that under the hood, OpenSea will call my contract's `safeTransferFrom` method, but that method is not `payable` so how do I get paid for secondary sales?

Before I test on an OpenSea test network and everything, I'm trying to write some unit tests with [hardhat](http://hardhat.org/)/[ethers](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/) and running into an issue testing secondary sales/royalties. OpenSea has [some documentation](https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/1500009575482-How-do-royalties-work-on-OpenSea-) about royalties but it doesn't mention EIP-2981 or custom contract integration at all. My test in question currently looks like this:

```
it("should send royalties to the payment splitter contract", async function () {
    await NFTContract.connect(account1).create(1, { value: utils.parseEther(NFT_PRICE) })
    expect(await NFTContract.ownerOf(0)).to.equal(await account1.getAddress())
    expect(await ethers.provider.getBalance(paymentContract.address)).to.equal(utils.parseEther(NFT_PRICE))

    // transfer NFT to a new wallet
    await NFTContract["transferFrom(address,address,uint256)"](await account1.getAddress(), await account2.getAddress(), 0, { value: utils.parseEther(NFT_PRICE) })
    expect(await NFTContract.ownerOf(0)).to.equal(await account2.getAddress())
})
```

but when I run it I get the error:

```
secondary sale roaylties
   should send royalties to the payment splitter contract:
     Error: non-payable method cannot override value (operation="overrides.value", value={"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0xd529ae9e860000"}, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.5.0)
```

Obviously I can remove the `{ value: utils.parseEther(NFT_PRICE) }` from the transferFrom call, but logically that doesn't make sense to me because then the user is transferring the NFT/token without getting paid. So, what does OpenSea call under the hood when a secondary sale is made and how can I test that locally?

Comment: Can you include the code of the functions being called? seems like the problem is there

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?